# chef Check Convergence/Resource Status in Local Mode

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, dsc

Is there an easy way to check for convergence or "up-to-date" status on a node when running chef-client in local mode? I know I can see "x of # resources updated" at the end of the console output, but is there something deterministic I can call? Like with DSC, I can call

```
Test-DscConfiguration
```

or

```
Get-DscConfigurationStatus
```

Is there any kind of similar api to check if a node is in its desired state?

Answer (score 1):

Chef has a pseudo-dry-run mode via `chef-client --why-run`. Because Chef uses real Ruby code, it can never be 100% sure if running something will have side effects or not. Why Run requires explicit coordination from all resources being used (all core ones support it), but is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an api I can call or get some exit code to support success?

Comment: You would probably have to parse the output. Because it's only best-effort, Why Run is generally not used for automation. You would just run chef-client as needed and it makes the system match the desired config.

Comment: Is there a more "chef-like" approach to desired state? Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Rather than checking if the machine is in a good state, you would just run a converge and know that it is (or that the converge failed if there is a non zero exit)

Comment: by converge do you just mean "chef-client" with no options?

Comment: Yes, generally. A lot of people also run `chef-client` as a daemon or via cron.